# In C, are large 'pointer chains' bad for performance or code cleanliness?

Tags: c++, c, coding-standards

The following for example:

```
i = readString(&packet->data.play_server.updatesign.line1, pbuf, ps);
```

It has a large amount of nested structs/unions. Is this generally frowned upon in code cleanliness, or bad for performance?

Comment: There is only one pointer dereference `->` in the example you're showing.  The `.` operator has no performance cost in C/C++, as the items are embedded together.

Comment: In the OO world it's usually a sign that you have poor encapsulation and are violating the Single Responsibility Principle.  I have no idea about the C world.

Comment: Search for the “[Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)”. It can also be applied to C.

Comment: That's why I said 'pointer chains', I'm talking about just long lines of referencing.

Comment: @JavaProphet: Your example did not include "long lines of referencing". Or dereferencing. That's why people are confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad for performance is questionable in your example. True runtime pointer dereferencing in sequence can be bad for cache coherency. But your example doesn't show this; it only has one runtime pointer to dereference.

C is a statically typed language. Therefore, at compile time, the compiler knows the sizes and layout of every member subobject of every object. So `.play_server.updatesign.line1` basically compiles down to a static integer offset of a pointer. It becomes `&packet->data + static_offset` (using byte addition rather than C pointer arithmetic).

If those `.`s had been `->`s instead, that would be a different matter. Each such pointer could at runtime be any particular value. And therefore, the compiler can't boil everything down to a static offset; it has to be executed at runtime as a chain of accesses, each one reading a pointer from the next object. And thus, like iterating through a linked list, it can be bad for cache coherency and so forth.

As for code cleanliness, that all rather depends on where you are and what you're doing. If `packet->data` is just a plain data structure with no need for invariants, then it's fine. Those subobjects are just aggregates, not smart containers that need encapsulation. If there is some invariant in play within this data structure, then direct modification of such a data structure would violate encapsulation and thus be dangerous.

Then again, providing encapsulation in C usually requires hiding declarations (forward declarations and so forth), which tends to make inlining difficult. And if each of those sub-object accesses were an encapsulated action, that could represent the kind of "pointer chain" that you are concerned about, since the compiler would not easily be able to compile accesses down to a static offset. So C programs tend to employ encapsulation at the boundaries of major systems or APIs, rather than within individual systems themselves.

What is clean to one programmer isn't clean to another.